# Listing down nearby places android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been able to retrieve different nearby places but I want to put them in the list where the user can see and select the places using the list.

I retrieve these places using :

```
 static String makeURL1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + radiusplace.inputtedradius);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + "art_gallery");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyCx8-ZK6m5FTgEoTaSRaUuALV-5Vnz1Co4");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}

public void getplaces() {
    String url = null;


    try {
        url = makeURL1();
     

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    placesAsyncTask download = new placesAsyncTask(url);
   
    download.execute();

}
```

How to put all places in the list that is being showed on the map?

My idea is like this 
[image: e.]

I have button filter on the top where the user can freely manage the places he want to see and in the content, it will show the pictures and the information about specific plac

Comment: Use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Comment: I know i will use ListView or RecycleView, I'm looking for a guide in putting the places on the list.

Comment: By guide you mean some sort of tutorial on `RecyclerView` which explains how do you show data using it?

Comment: Yes, On how I'm going to put the data of the places in the RecyclerView.

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/ hope this will help u

Answer (score 2):

To know how to show data using `RecyclerView` refer this [Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/)

And this kind of operations are very common for android apps. So if you google it with your query then it must give you the desired help that other developers have already provided on their blogs or on other StackOverflow question.